# Celery task fails to write to home dir when Celery runs under supervisord

Tags: python, celery, supervisord

I'm running Celery with Redis as a broker in virtualenv. I have a usual shell script to start celeryd. I have a task that writes a temp files to $HOME/.tmp. I start the celery task from Django python shell using  mytask.delay(arg1, arg2). The task works as expected when I launch celery manually - open terminal and ./celeryd_start (shown below). However when I start celery using supervisor the task fails as it cannot write the tmp file. Supervisor is configured to start celery using the same shell script and under the same user I launch it manually.

I don't know what's going, the supervisor celery process runs under the same user that is used to start celery manually, it should have the same permissions. I tried setting umask=000 in the supervisor config file but this made no change.

Is there any supervisor setting I need to change to make it work?

I tried setting the permissions to 777 and changing the location to tmp to no avail. The script uses the following command to create the temp dir.

```
mkdir -p $HOME/./tmp/ && chmod a+rx $HOME/.tmp/
```

supervisor config:

```
[program:apl_dev_celeryd]
; Set full path to celery program if using virtualenv
command=/home/kp/apl/dev/bin/celeryd_start
user=kp
numprocs=1
stdout_logfile=/home/kp/apl/dev/logs/worker_stdout.log
stderr_logfile=/home/kp/apl/dev/logs/worker_stderr.log
autostart=true
autorestart=true
startsecs=10

stopwaitsecs = 10

killasgroup=true

priority=993
```

celeryd_start

```
#!/bin/bash

NAME="apl_dev_celeryd"                              # Name of the application
DJANGODIR=/home/kp/apl/dev/p                 # Django project directory
APP_NAME=p                                      # which celery app is run
LOG_LEVEL=DEBUG                                 # valid values DEBUG, INFO, WARNING, ERROR, CRITICAL, FATAL
CONCURRENCY=2                                   # number of worker processes
echo "Starting $NAME as `whoami`"

# Activate the virtual environment
cd $DJANGODIR
source ../bin/activate
export PYTHONPATH=$DJANGODIR:$PYTHONPATH

# Create the run directory if it doesn't exist

# Start celeryd
# Programs meant to be run under supervisor should not daemonize themselves (do not use --daemon)
exec celery -A $APP_NAME worker --loglevel=$LOG_LEVEL --concurrency=$CONCURRENCY
```

python 2.7.3
celery 3.1.16
ubuntu 12.04

Answer (score 0):

Looks like the supervised process is not handling the environmental variables properly.

Setting :

```
environment=HOME="/tmp/.tmp/"
```

in the supervisor's config for the process solved the problem.